# generate random sample from arbitrary 2d discrete distribution

Tags: sampling, random-generation, bivariate

I have a custom, discrete probability map (2d) that I would like to randomly sample from. I understand that in 1d case, this can be done easily using the inverse transform sampling method. However, it seems that people are saying this can't be done in 2d discrete distributions.

Is that true? If so, is there a fast way of sampling from a 2d discrete distribution?

Comment: All you do is two coordinate independent random sampling z(Rand(1), Rand(2)). How is that a problem?

Comment: Welcome to [stats.se]!  Please take a moment to view our [tour].  While not a duplicate, the method and answer to this question might be helpful: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/247305/statistical-test-to-compare-a-single-value-with-a-simulated-set-of-random-values

Comment: hmm, but the 2d discrete probability map has correlations and the two dimensions aren't independent, so if I just perform independent ransom sampling on each of the 2 dimensions, wouldn't that be inaccurate?

Comment: Figured out how this can be done: compute the cdf of 1d marginal, pick an uniform random position just like the inverse transform sampling method; then, do this again on the 2nd dimension by conditioning on the already sampled position from the previous step.

Comment: If you've found a solution you're satisfied with, do consider adding it as an answer (and accepting it).

Comment: This answer may also be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31675310/1054120